# Visual Studio 2010: Can it be used from client machine?

Tags: 2010

SP2010 and Visual 2010

I'm a site collection administrator and have been doing all SP development using SPD.  However, I just got Visual Studio 2010 installed on my machine (SP hosted on a server elsewhere).

Question is, can I use visual studio w/o SP installed on my machine?  I've tried w/no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You can use sharepoint web services, and/or CSOM (with CSOM you need the distributable assemblies found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b4579045-b183-4ed4-bf61-dc2f0deabe47)). You cannot use Server side object model code. Using Web services or CSOM, you can develop solutions using Visual Studios with out being on a server.

More info on CSOM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247(v=office.14).aspx
More info on web services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979690(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 2):

there are 3 different things

development, deployment and debugging

development can in fact be done through the "registry tweak" to bypass the "you need sharepoint installed" message when creating projects. you will need to grab the dlls from the isapi folder

> Export the hive [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared
>   Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0] from the sp machine and install on
>   the local machine
>
> Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\web
>   server extensions\14.0\" -Name "Location" -Value "C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\"

remote deployment is also a possibility but as you will find, you are better off deploying the solution manually with powershell once you have it

debugging is also problematic, but not impossible

sources:

[here](http://techblog.hk.agenda-asia.com/2010/10/29/create-sharepoint-project-without-install-sharepoint-server/)

[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950548/sharepoint-2010-development-without-local-server-installation)

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes, **NO**.  Technically, yeah, you can write apps that communicate with SharePoint, and ok, you can tweak Visual Studio to develop SharePoint solutions using a number of hacks, but if your intention is to actually get real-world work done in a timely fashion, this is a setup for failure.

SharePoint development is difficult enough with a properly configured dev environment.